# Json to List view Conversion retriving null values in xmarian.forms cross platform

Tags: xamarin.forms.listview

Am trying to convert JSON data to list but its showing null. my code and JSON data like below.But in the list (`lst`) it showing `null`.

**JSON:**

```
{"Data":[{"LocationId":6,"LocationName":"abc","ServiceUrl":"www.google.com", },{"LocationId":3,"LocationName":"abcd","ServiceUrl":"192.168.0.110/IKLT/service.svc"}],"ErrorCode":"201 - Success","Message":"Success","Status":true}
```

**Code:**

```
GetLocationResult lst= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetLocationResult>(result);

GetLocationResult   lr = (GetLocationResult)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result, typeof(GetLocationResult));
```

`GetLocationResult`    is a class for above JSON

Answer (score 0):

I inspected your json string, the syntax is wrong. Remove the extra comma shown in the picture below:

[image: JSON Object]